# Is this correct markup - empty element OR use css/js to achieve same effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantics, pseudo-class

I have a situation where I need to have a separator between 2 items as shown in the plunk. I could think of 2 methods for this to do as

1) Put an empty span between items and style it like separator
HTML:

```
  <body>
    <nav>
      <section class="icon1">Icon1</section>
      <span class="separator"></span>
      <section class="icon2">Icon2</section>
    </nav>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
nav {height:40px; background:yellow; width:300px; padding:0 10px;}
.icon1{ background:green; width:40px; height:100%; float:left;}
.icon2 {background:red; width:40px; height:100%; float:left;}
.separator{width:2px; height:100%; background:blue; float:left;}
```

2) Use :before psuedo selector for 2nd item and style it accordingly

HTML:

```
  <body>
    <nav>
      <section class="icon1">Icon1</section>
      <section class="icon2">Icon2</section>
    </nav>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
nav {height:40px; background:yellow; width:300px; padding:0 10px;}
.icon1{ background:green; width:40px; height:100%; float:left;}
.icon2 {background:red; width:40px; height:100%; float:left;}
.icon2:before{content:""; border-left:2px solid blue; position:absolute; height:40px;}
```

Plunk - http://plnkr.co/edit/a26btGkR8p5xcQeSxJiV?p=preview
The plunk is for both options 1 and 2 combined, please un comment, if you would like to check.

Now, I have an action which is taken when user clicks on the 2nd item, which is a modal popover will open up and that 2nd item is highlighted i.e. it is over & above the backdrop.

If I use 2) above i.e. :before, and then I click on 2nd item, the modal popover shows, the 2nd item highlights but that separator also gets highlighted since technically it is inside that element. I do not want that separator to be highlighted, so, to make it appear like its faded, I am writing few lines of js to toggle its opacity ( on click of 2nd item) so it looks like its faded.

If I use 1) i.e. empty span there is no problem at all, no need to write js, it simply works fine.

So, my problem here is whether I

**should use an empty span**

OR

**use :before and do some js**

Which one would be semantically correct and also which one would be less burden on page.

Comment: See browser compatibility table at http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent and decide. `<span>` works everywhere.

Comment: @KunJ - I am not really worried about browser compatibility because in my case, we are just supporting all modern browsers i.e. no old IE's, so thats not an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the 2nd solution, since the separator is probably not necessary for a (probably handicapped) user to understand the context.

Comment: But wouldnt that pile up extra work i.e both css and js instead of having it simply in just empy element? I am just trying to understand it a little deeper.

Comment: Yes, it would. But in my opinion, this is the fairly clearer solution, since it doesn't add HTML elements which aren't needed to understand your navigation and might confuse screen readers.

Answer (score 2):

**Both ways are semantically correct .** 
i would recommend using the

`<span class="separator"></span>` method so that you can move your second icon with out worrying about the separator positioning .

for sure  the ::before is more performance consuming ( definitely not noticeable )

- remember that you also can use borders to make easy simple separators  .

Comment: Well, if I use borders, that will also be highlighted, since that are a part of the element. I had tried that, but that wont help. Thanks for the advice though. I am still confused between the 2 options, is there a way we can measure the performance consumption in both cases?

Comment: yes you can , use firebug .. it will give you the exact time in ms